# IntelliJ Can't resolve java.util modules across repositories

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build

I've been having some trouble getting intellij building lately and was taking some steps to resolve the issues. In that process I ended up getting errors in intellij for multiple repositories, even though I didn't touch the .idea folder in both repos.

[image: intellij errors]

So this is what I've done so far to address the issue:

- try building from command line (mvn install) → no issues
- Generate Sources and Update Folders / Reload Project → doesn't help
- Invalidate Caches and restart → doesn't help
- Delete the .idea folder for the repo → doesn't help (I think this is what led to the problem but I only deleted this folder in the one repo, not the other repo)

Any thoughts on what else can be done for this?

System Info

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-203.7717.56, built on March 15, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+8-b1145.96 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 3451M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins: CheckStyle-IDEA, com.dubreuia, com.github.kisstkondoros.codemetrics, org.jetbrains.jumpToLine, org.sonarlint.idea, intellij.prettierJS, Pythonid
```

Comment: Last time when I ran into this issue, I had to downgrade the IntelliJ to a lower version

Comment: Please try to remove and then add project SDK.

Comment: adding and removing the SDK didn't help, and I'll try updating my IntelliJ instead, I haven't updated it since installing half a year ago

Answer (score 1):

Updating intellij solved my issue:

New System Info

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-203.8084.24, built on April 27, 2021


Runtime version: 11.0.10+8-b1145.96 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 3451M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins: CheckStyle-IDEA, com.dubreuia, com.github.kisstkondoros.codemetrics, org.jetbrains.jumpToLine, org.sonarlint.idea, intellij.prettierJS, Pythonid
```